# Trying to use a getMethod to access data and use it in another class

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a `getMethod` to access data from `form1.cs` and use it in another class. Here I am getting errors that I do not understand.

Error :

```
"Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" and
"Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration".
```

The following is code:

Method inside `form1.cs` :

```
// select_emp_id_number is an INT

    public int get_select_emp_id_number()
    {
        return select_emp_id_number;
    }
```

Code in `Absence class` : I am trying to get the Data from form1.cs

```
    private int a = 0;
    Form1 test = new Form1();
    a = test.get_select_emp_id_number();
```

I didn't see anything wrong here. Can anyone see where I did wrong & help me

Comment: You cannot have an assignment (the third line) directly inside a class. It has to be inside a method or constructor.

Comment: Show more code before and after `private int a = 0`. Now it is not clear whether this is in class, method, etc.

Comment: And you probably don't want to instantiate a **new** Form1 but use the one that's already shown to the user.

Comment: This chunk lies before private in a = 0
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace EmployeePerformanceSystem
{
    class Absence
    {

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your calling code is inside a function. You may not declare a variable as `private` inside a function.

change

```
private int a = 0;
```

to

```
int a = 0;
```

or simply

```
int a = test.get_select_emp_id_number();
```

Or if you have your code inside the class and not in a function, move the part

```
a = test.get_select_emp_id_number();
```

inside a function or the constructor

**Edit**:

According to your comments, maybe this example can help you. You can pass a reference to `Form1` (or better an interface that Form1 implements) to your `Absence` class:

```
public class Absence
{
    private Form1 form1;

    public Absence(Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
    }

    private void MyFunction()
    {
        int a = form1.get_select_emp_id_number();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have previously tried this approach, I receive a different error when doing this - "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'EPS.Absence.test'" - I am not clear on how to fix this.

Comment: Does a have to be a field or do you just need it as a variable inside the function?

Comment: Im not concerned how I get the data, as long as it is available in the absence class, I need to use the data for SQL purposes

Comment: Is `Absence` another form or just some class?

Comment: its just a normal class

Comment: Please see my edit. Have to go now. Maybe I can help later if you still have problems

Comment: I have tried your edit method, it runs. However I am trying to test it, so I absorbed the emp_id and then stored it in a int TESTemp and added 100 to it. I made a getTESTemp to return TESTemp to form1 - i used the same method again as you have shown - it compiles but it does not pick up on the new return TESTemp which has been stored as int ggg in form1. The TESTemp is suppose to be stored in ggg when a button is clicked, and then display it as a label on window. I get 'System.NullReferenceException', but wen i set it to 0 it works - meaning it is not picking up on the return TESTemp (ggg).

Comment: INSIDE Absense class:

private Form1 form1;

public Absence(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1 = form1;
}

public void MyFunction()
{
    a = form1.get_select_emp_id_number();
    TESTemp = a + 100;
}

public int getTESTemp()
{
    MyFunction();
    return TESTemp;
}

INSIDE form1 class:

int ggg = 0;

private Absence absence;

public Form1(Absence absence)
{
    this.absence = absence;
}

private void MyFunction()
{
    ggg = absence.getTESTemp();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyFunction();
    this.label6.Text = ggg.ToString();
}

Comment: The problem is most probably that the constructor `Form1(Absence absence)` is never called and so the field `private Absence absence` is not initialized. Instead the parameterless constructor is called (check in the debugger)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than,

```
private int a = 0;
```

try:

```
int a = test.get_select_emp_id_number();
```

The reason for this, is that you cannot declare private variables in a function. Instead they are used to define the variables availability to other classes in the solution.

Comment: I have previously tried this approach, I receive a different error when doing this - "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'EPS.Absence.test'" - I am not clear on how to fix this.

Comment: @CashMoney you have to put this line in the constructor of your class or main method depending where you use it.